# Why does the 'mypy' module report a type incompatibility error for a variable which is a tuple having container type elements?

Tags: python

I encounter a question when I use the module `mypy` to check the type of values of variables in my code. It can be demonstrated in the example as below:

```
from typing import Set, Tuple

x: Set[tuple] = {('a', 100, True),
                 ('b', 200, False)}

y: Tuple[tuple] = (('a', 100, True),
                   ('b', 200, False))
```

The only difference between variables `x` and `y` is that `x` is a set and `y` is a tuple. Except that, they contain the same elements. But when I ran `mypy` to check this code, it reported the following error for line 6:

```
test.py:6: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Tuple[Tuple[str, int, bool], Tuple[str, int, bool]]", variable has type "Tuple[Tuple[Any, ...]]")  [ass
ignment]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I got confused. Why did `mypy` report an error for incompatible types in line 6 of my example? And why was the same error not reported for line 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tuple[tuple]` means a tuple containing *exactly one* tuple, not a tuple of tuples. A tuple of tuples is `Tuple[tuple, ...]`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are right. I think I did not read the document of ` mypy ` conscientiously enough beforehand. I fixed this problem by changing the type hint of ` y ` to ` Tuple[tuple, ...] `. But I think it is easy to be confused while the type hint ` Set[Tuple] ` can be used for a variable referring to a set containing tuple type elements but ` Tuple[tuple] ` can not be used for a variable referring to a tuple containing tuple type elements.